# Var won't exceed billion

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, digits

**EDIT**

I tested something out, and apparently, this:

```
if(info.max.value == "") {maxdesiredvalue = 999999999999999999999}
```

Returns in the chrome console:

```
> maxdesiredvalue
< 999999999
```

So I believe the problem really comes from there... is there a maximum number of digits we can attribute to a variable?

---

I'm into javascript for a few months now, and I've made a program that generates random weapons for a tabletop rpg.
Every weapon generated has a price relative to it's attributes. My problem today is that this price won't exceed 9 digits (cannot reach billion), even though it can.
In my generator, it is possible to choose certain properties before generating the weapon. If I intentionally try to generate something worth over a billion gold, it will crash instantly. On the other hand, if there is any way the weapon can be generated without exceeding the billion, it will do so.

For example, the most expansive metal is the "Residuum". The only 2 weapons that can be generated in Residuum are the dart and the shuriken, since they only use 1/16 of an Ingot. Therefore if I set the metal to be Residuum, they will be the only 2 possible generated weapons. From this point, if I try to specify I want a Residuum Sword, it will simply crash as explained earlier.

In my generation options, I also have a text input for the user to choose a minimum value and/or a maximum value for the weapon. I set the default max value to Infinity, so it should'nt be a problem.

```
function desiredvalue(){

        if(info.max.value == "") {maxdesiredvalue = Infinity}
        else {maxdesiredvalue = parseInt(info.max.value)}

        if(info.min.value == "") {mindesiredvalue = 0}
        else {mindesiredvalue = parseInt(info.min.value)}

    }
```

In my html:

```
Min price: <input type="text" name="min" value="" onchange="desiredvalue()">
Max price: <input type="text" name="max" value="" onchange="desiredvalue()">
```

I already tried to deactivate this function to see if it was the problem, but even without a specific max value, weapons still won't be generated if their value exceeds 9 digits.

Maybe the problem sets inside the value formula, so here it is, even though it might not be a big help since it is all made up from variables.

```
WeapValue = ((((IngotValue * Ingots) + CraftTime + (actualEnchantTime * 3) + (LS * 0.02) + (R * 0.05) + BS + (FTH * 0.03)) * (((BPArace + BPAstatus + BPAlevel + ((BPAcrit1 + 1) * BPAcrit2)) / 100) + 1)) + PAenchant + PAaugment1 + PAaugment2 + PAaugment3)
```

Also the value is modified afterwards to fit in gold, silver or copper...

```
WeapValue.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 0});
WeapValue = WeapValue.toFixed(2);

if (WeapValue >= 2) {WeapValue2 = Math.ceil(WeapValue); goldtype = " GP"}
else if (WeapValue < 2 && WeapValue >= 1) {WeapValue2 = WeapValue * 10; goldtype = " SP"}
else if (WeapValue < 1 && WeapValue >= 0) {WeapValue2 = WeapValue * 100; goldtype = " CP"}
```

Nothing else in the script really change the value, and all the variables affecting it are defined earlier, and I don't really think they are the problem, since they actually seem to work (they simply make the price exceed 9 digits).

If you have any questions related to the script, I'm here to answer, but I can't put the full script since it is very, very long (2543 lines)...

If anyone has an idea of how I can deal with my problem, it would be so appreciated! Again, I'm not a javascript expert, but I did my best and looked a lot on the Internet for help, but I still can't get rid of this problem...

Thank you!

Comment: A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be really helpful.

Comment: Tried something, I think I found where the problem comes from. See edit for details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)